# Semantically Compare Programs by Similarity?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

In NLP, it's common to study the semantic similarity between pieces of text, which can be calculated in a number of ways. Are there any tools, methods, algorithms or processes that can be used to compare the semantic similarity of programs? That is, compare if two programs produce a similar output given similar inputs. There are a few obvious methods that I can think of, like comparing two programs' outputs over a given set of inputs, but if there are an infinite number of possible inputs to the program, then that method would never be complete.

Speaking abstractly, I don't think there's a way to semantically compare two arbitrary Turing machines in any meaningful way. After all, the equivalence problem for Turing machines is undecidable. But for simpler classes of programs describable as, say, a FSM, is there any useful similarity metric?

Comment: Googling on `regular language "similarity"` produces quite a few hits, but I really think the kind of similarity you want to consider depends on your objective. What is more similar to the regular expression $a(a\cup bc)^*b$, is it the regular expression $a(a\cup bd)^*b$ (different by 1 character) or is it a regular expression that produces all strings in $L(a(a\cup bc)^*b)$ shorter than 1000 characters?

Comment: I sympathize with your question. Unfortunately, there are probably many ways one could define a similarity metric, each of which might be useful in different situations.  I suspect you'll need to offer some criteria or design goals you want a similarity metric to satisfy, for it to be possible to narrow down the question to an answerable state.